# NodeJS: Can't sign in nodeJS 10.14.2

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I read the following https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_sign and tried to copy the code:

> sign.js

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const { privateKey, publicKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('ec', {
  namedCurve: 'sect239k1'
});

const sign = crypto.createSign('SHA256');
sign.write('some data to sign');
sign.end();
const signature = sign.sign(privateKey, 'hex');

const verify = crypto.createVerify('SHA256');
verify.write('some data to sign');
verify.end();
console.log(verify.verify(publicKey, signature));
// Prints: true or false
```

But it throws me an error

```
>> node sign.js  
internal/crypto/keygen.js:73
    throw new ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE('publicKeyEncoding', publicKeyEncoding);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE]: The value "undefined" is invalid for option "publicKeyEncoding"
    at parseKeyEncoding (internal/crypto/keygen.js:73:11)
    at check (internal/crypto/keygen.js:240:7)
    at Object.generateKeyPairSync (internal/crypto/keygen.js:53:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/norfeldt/Desktop/AsymEnc/sign.js:3:42)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
```

## Update

I made the following change (as suggested by @ottomeister)

```
const crypto = require('crypto')

const { privateKey, publicKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('ec', {
  namedCurve: 'sect239k1',
  publicKeyEncoding: { type: 'spki', format: 'der' },
  privateKeyEncoding: { type: 'pkcs8', format: 'der' },
})

const sign = crypto.createSign('SHA256')
sign.write('some data to sign')
sign.end()
const signature = sign.sign(privateKey, 'hex')

const verify = crypto.createVerify('SHA256')
verify.write('some data to sign')
verify.end()
console.log(verify.verify(publicKey, signature))
// Prints: true or false
```

But it now throws me a new error

```
internal/crypto/sig.js:80
  var ret = this._handle.sign(key, passphrase, rsaPadding, pssSaltLength);

Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
    at Sign.sign (internal/crypto/sig.js:80:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/norfeldt/Desktop/AsymEnc/sign.js:12:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:282:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

(I don't know it makes a difference, but I would like to read `.pem` files I create with openssl)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say you're using Node.js version 10 but your link points to the documentation for Node.js version 11.  The documentation for version 10 is at https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/crypto.html

In version 11, the `publicKeyEncoding` and `privateKeyEncoding` properties of the `options` object passed as the second argument to `crypto.generateKeyPairSync` are optional.  In version 10 these properties are not optional, they **must** be specified.  Your program doesn't provide those properties, and that's why it's blowing up.

If you change:

```
const { privateKey, publicKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('ec', {
  namedCurve: 'sect239k1'
});
```

to:

```
const { privateKey, publicKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('ec', {
  namedCurve: 'sect239k1',
  publicKeyEncoding:  { type: 'spki', format: 'der' },
  privateKeyEncoding: { type: 'pkcs8', format: 'der' }
});
```

then your program should be much happier.

---

## Update

OK, I installed Node 10 and ran your program.  `sign.sign()` is blowing up because, as stated in the documentation, it requires the private key to be in PEM format.  It can't handle a private key in the DER format my original answer produced.  The same applies to the format of the public key passed to `verify.verify()` -- it must be PEM, not DER.  So change this:

```
const { privateKey, publicKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('ec', {
  namedCurve: 'sect239k1',
  publicKeyEncoding:  { type: 'spki', format: 'der' },
  privateKeyEncoding: { type: 'pkcs8', format: 'der' }
});
```

to this:

```
const { privateKey, publicKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('ec', {
  namedCurve: 'sect239k1',
  publicKeyEncoding:  { type: 'spki', format: 'pem' },
  privateKeyEncoding: { type: 'pkcs8', format: 'pem' }
});
```

That is, change both occurrences of `'der'` to `'pem'`.

That will let your program run without throwing exceptions.  However, the verification attempt will fail and the reported result written by the final `console.log()` call will be `false`.  That's because the program does not tell `verify.verify()` the encoding that was used in the `privateKey` string.  To fix that and get a `true` result from the verification, change:

```
verify.verify(publicKey, signature)
```

to:

```
verify.verify(publicKey, signature, 'hex')
```

matching the string encoding that was specified when the signature was generated by `sign.sign()`.  The documentation isn't very clear on this part, but from experimentation it seems that if the signature is a string then you must always specify the encoding of the string.  The only circumstance in which you can skip providing the encoding here is if you also skip it in the `sign.sign()` call, which would have caused `signature` to be generated as a `Buffer` rather than as a string.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing this out to me! I wasn't aware of that I was looking at a future version. I tried what you suggested but still, have some troubles. See my updated question.

Comment: Thank you very much for updating your answer and helping me out!

Comment: +1 for clarifying necessity for passing `hex` to `verify()`. Documentation not only isn't clear on this part, but actually provides a [failing example](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_sign) by specifying `hex` in `sign()` and omitting it in `verify()` :/